# Как правильно настроить Apache в моем случае?

Tags: apache, apache2

Есть VPS, на котором стоит LAMP. И всего 2 директории wp1 и wp2. Мне нужно привязать домен site.com к папке wp1, а site.ru к папке wp2. Но у регистратора домена я могу прописать только IP адрес VPS. Я не могу вставить запись вида 105.170.98.108/wp1/. Как мне правильно настроить Apache в моем случае?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень распространенный вопрос, и выше абсолютно правильно написано — нужно использовать виртуальные хосты. Я бы хотел привести свою конфигурацию, которую считаю наиболее удобной.

Судя по названию дирректорий, у Вас wordpress. С чем связаны сложности, от которых не убежишь. Эти сложности — дыры в безопасности, и новичку лучше подкопить опыта перед настройкой боевого сервера, иначе вероятность подарить сервер 'хакерам' очень высока.

Конфиг vHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/home/hh-upper/public_html"
ServerName domain.ru
ServerAlias www.domain.ru
ServerAlias external.domain.ru
<Directory "/home/domain/public_html">
Allow from all
Options -Indexes
</Directory>

<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
   AssignUserId domain sites
</IfModule>

        ErrorLog /home/domain/logs/domain-error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /home/domain/logs/domain-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Итак, начнем разбирать...

1. `DocumentRoot` - основная директория сайта
2. `ServerName` - домен, который будет сопоставляться директории
3. `ServerAlias` - зеркало имени п.2
4. Начиная с `<Directory` идет конфигурация самой директории. Здесь важное - `Options -Indexes` - запрет листинга директории
5. Теперь самое вкусное `mpm_itk_module` - запуск скриптов, да и вообще выполнение в этом хосте будет происходить от прописанного в `AssignUserId` пользователя. Очень удобно, если несколько сайтов. Заполучив контроль надо одним сайтом не получится что-то сделать с другим). Для каждого сайта должен быть отдельный пользователь. Так же должен быть установлен указанный модуль, [вот инструкция](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/21382/). Если он не настроен - ошибки не будет.
6. `ErrorLog`, `LogLevel` и `CustomLog` - логирование apache для этого хоста. Его параметры можно подобрать и самому)

Всё достаточно просто. Если возникнут сложности, пиши, разберемся, поможем!

PS: Очень рекомендую поставить [mod_security](http://habrahabr.ru/post/145215/) на сервер, иначе можно хорошо поплатиться)

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо, чтобы DNS-сервера регистратора (если вы используете их) отдавали на запросы к site.com и site.ru ваш реальный ip-адрес. Дальше, вам необходимо в конфиг apache2 внести соответствующие изменения. Вот ссылка на [apache2 vHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html), на документацию apache2 (а именно на раздел посвященный виртуальным хостам), всё предельно ясно описано. Будут вопросы - пишите.